# refresh combobox and reselect the last item in C#

Tags: c#, list, combobox, refresh, items

I have made a combobox containing string (comboBox.Items.Add(string)) and once every few seconds I want to refresh it (it is a list of clients so some may connect / disconnect). The problem I'm having is that when I'm refreshing the list, it also changes the selected item to null and therefore cause problems if i'm trying to communicate with the last selected client (which means that I have to rechoose him after every tick)
my refresh code is:

```
prog.comboBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (string client in data.Split('#'))
{
      prog.comboBox1.Items.Add(client);
}
```

and the code I've tried to rechoose the item after refreshing (it doesn't work) is:

```
string previous = prog.comboBox1.GetItemText(prog.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
//Refresh list here (With the code above)
if (prog.comboBox1.Items.Contains(previous))
       prog.comboBox1.Text = previous;
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: how you refresh? is this web application?

Comment: Try to puffer the SelectedItem and set it back. If you set the `Text` you overwrite the Text of the (randomly) current item...

Comment: But if so, I'll have to save the previous item as an Object and won't be able to use the Contains attribute.

Comment: Does a client have an ID? It would be a lot easier to use a unique ID as a reference.

Comment: use `BindingList<T>` and set it to `ComboBox.DataSource` instead work with this `BindingList` instead of clearing list of combobox items directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be a good interface. An operator is selecting something and while he is pressing the mouse button down to click something the list is changed. Are you sure that this doesn't cause that the incorrect item is selected?

Compare this to selecting a file to be deleted in a file explorer. You select the file to delete and another process changes the contents of the folder, thus causing the incorrect file to be selected.

What would be selected if during the mouse click the selected item is not valid anymore? And what if the user clicks, averts his eyes to the OK button and does not see that he selected the incorrect item? Did you consider what would happen if the operator uses the keyboard and the arrow keys to select the item in the combo box?

This user interface is especially dangerous if you do the action upon selection instead of after selection and pressing an OK button.

If you look at other common windows application where things might change during selection you always see the following scenario:

- The moment the collection of items that can be selected becomes visible, the system determines the collection
- While this collection is visible, the collection does not change
- Selecting the item in the collection does not perform the action
- Only after the operator presses OK (or continue / next / whatever), the validity of the selection is checked.

If you add a confirmation button and use the following scenario, then you won't have your problem:

- Upon opening event of the combobox dropdown list you add the currently existing items
- The operator selects the item, and maybe selects other things
- Upon event of confirmation of the selection you check if all items that are selected are still valid and continue or show some error via an errorprovider or a message box.

So I advise you to reconsider your user interface by adding a confirmation button, operators will thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
// to prevent re-drawing
prog.comboBox1.BeginUpdate();

try {
  // swicth event processing off: 
  // do not pay attention to selected index changing while refresing the combo
  prog.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= prog.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

  try {
    prog.comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    // You don't want the foreach loop...
    prog.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(data.Split('#'));
  }
  finally {
    // swicth event processing back on
    prog.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += prog.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
  }

  // Finally, select the item
  prog.comboBox1.Items.SelectedIndex = ... 
}
finally {
  prog.comboBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```